# How do I replace a string within an XML form post parameter in a web performance test?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, performance-testing

I'm testing a web application that usually sends some fairly large XML structures to the app's web services when communicating back to the web server.  Of course, I need to vary the test data - replacing some elements with data from a data source - for each iteration of the test run.  Is there a syntax for putting tokens into the recorded XML parameters so that the web performance test will replace the data from a database, another data source, or a Context Parameter during test runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple to accomplish, using double curly brackets around the data source name as in the following example:

```
<Message>
{{DataSource.TableName.ColumnName}}
</Message>
```

You can use a context parameter in the parameter as follows:

```
<Message>
{{ContextParameterName}}
</Message>
```

This also works with non-XML form post parameters.

Comment: For those using Json and VS 2012, this answer also applies! E.g., if I have a DataSource PersonIds.csv, I can add my Form Post Parameter and give it a value: [{"PersonId": "{{DataSource1.PersonIds#csv.PersonId}}"}]

Comment: Thanks for that extra tip Daniel!